# Perl syntaxt to vb.net conversion help needed

Tags: vb.net, perl

I am looking for help to understand Perl syntax. I am trying to convert a telephony Perl script to vb.net and I am having a hard time understanding what is going on. Trying look on the web to decipher the code below in Perl, such as creating variables on the fly, fat commas, etc. is just spinning my head.

So, in the following Perl code snippet, some kind of string gets assembled, sent to the phone switch to get the status of phone 429. If the status is not "V" the string gets scrubbed and the script moves onto the next set of instructions.

Could someone translate this code snippet to vb.net?

Thank you in advance!

```
  foreach my $class (1 .. 9) { $sess->AddMsgClass( CLASS => $class ); }
  my %filter = ( NUMFIELDS=>2, CONDITION1=>1, NUM1=>ord("I"), CONDITION2=>1, NUM2=>429 );
  $sess->AddCompoundFilter( ID=>"DEST", FIELD1=>5, FIELD2=>6, (%filter) );
  $sess->AddCompoundFilter( ID=>"ORIG", FIELD1=>3, FIELD2=>4, (%filter));
  $sess->AddCompoundFilter( ID=>"EVENTS", FIELD1=>18, FIELD2=>19, (%filter));

  my $e = $sess->EquipmentStatus( SUBTYPE=>"ESR", EQUIPTYPE=>"I", EQUIPMENT=>429 );
  if ($e->{"STATUS"} ne "V") {
    foreach my $class (1 .. 9) { $sess->DelMsgClass( CLASS => $class ); }
    foreach my $filter ( "DEST", "ORIG", "EVENTS" ) { $sess->DelCompoundFilter( ID => $filter ); }
```

}

Comment: So, does this make sence for the first three lines?      return    `For Each intNumber In objClass
            Session.AddMsgClass("CLASS", intNumber)
        Next

        Dim hshFilter As Hashtable = New Hashtable
        hshFilter.Add("NUMFIELDS", 2)
        hshFilter.Add("CONDITION1", 1)
        hshFilter.Add("NUM1", "I")
        hshFilter.Add("CONDITION2", "I")
        hshFilter.Add("NUM2", 429)

        Session.AddCompoundFilter("ID", "DEST", "FIELD1", 5, "FIELD2", 6, hshFilter)`

Comment: Yes.  Looks good to me. Of course, you've got to rewrite the Session class as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach my $class (1 .. 9) { $sess->AddMsgClass( CLASS => $class ); }
```

1..9 is a range operator.  Imagine a list of numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  The foreach takes each of those numbers in turn, assigns it to the variable $class, and then does everything in the block (set of curly braces) that follow, which is this: $sess->AddMsgClass( CLASS => $class ).  $sess should be a reference to an instance of a class that has a method called "AddMessageClass" - so it calls that method, passing as a parameter the key-value pair CLASS and the value of $class (which was 1 the first time, then 2 the second, and so on.

Then the next line:

```
my %filter = ( NUMFIELDS=>2, CONDITION1=>1, NUM1=>ord("I"), CONDITION2=>1, NUM2=>429 );
```

Declares and defines a hash (same as a Dictionary in VB).  The hash as a whole is referred to as %filter but if you want to get the value of one of the keys, use this: $filter{'NUMFIELDS'} (which will equal 2)

The next three lines are essentially the same:

```
$sess->AddCompoundFilter( ID=>"DEST", FIELD1=>5, FIELD2=>6, (%filter) );
```

This uses the same $sess object as in line 1, but this time it calls the AddCompoundFilter method on that object.  As parameters it passes a dictionary object consisting of three key-value pairs, ID=>'DEST', FIELD1=>5, FIELD2=>6 as well as all of the key-value pairs that were defined in %filter in the line above.  This is just like merging two dictionary objects and passing the result as the parameter.

Then this line:

```
  my $e = $sess->EquipmentStatus( SUBTYPE=>"ESR", EQUIPTYPE=>"I", EQUIPMENT=>429 );
```

The same $sess object also has a method called "EquipmentStatus".  It calls that method, passing as parameters another dictionary with three key-value pairs.  The method returns a value which is assigned to the variable $e.  The "my" just declares that variable.

Then the next line:

```
  if ($e->{"STATUS"} ne "V") {
```

$e is the variable we got back from the method call above.  Apparently it was an object reference or maybe just a hash (dictionary) reference.  In any case, it looks up the value of the STATUS property of that and compares it, using string comparison, to the letter "V".  The "ne" is string comparison - that ensures both sides are interpreted as strings.  If it had said "!=" then they would have both been converted to numbers.

I hope that helps!

There's a bit of a learning curve with Perl but it's totally worthwhile.

(Edited to add more content)

Comment: That is really helpful. Could you also fill me in about lines 2-5? Also, could you include some quick .net translation line by line?

Comment: I added details on those lines.  My VB is a bit rusty so you can probably do a better job of translating it.